# Sort array of dicts in python based on other array

Tags: python, sorting

I have an array of dicts, `[{'id': 1, 'name': 'one'}, {'id':2, 'name': 'two'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}]` and the array with sorted ids `[3, 1, 2]`

The expected result is

`[{'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'two'}]`

What is the best way to do this?

My code is based on two for:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'one'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'two'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}]
b = [3, 1, 2]

res = []

for index in b:
    for player in a:
        if index == player['id']:
            res.append(player)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(a, key=lambda d: b.index(d['id']))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
>>> a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'one'}, {'id':2, 'name': 'two'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}]
>>> b = [3,1,2]
>>> sorted(a, key= lambda x: l.index(x['id']))
[{'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'two'}]
```